# Como retornar apenas os registros sem correspondência em um JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-select

Tenho uma duvida em relação ao uso de `JOIN` em SQL neste caso:

Tenho uma tabela `produtos` e uma tabela `destaques` que contém o `id` do produto. Preciso fazer uma consulta que retorne somente os registros que **não estão** na tabela destaques.

Tentei isto:

```
SELECT p.* FROM produto p
INNER JOIN destaques d ON p.idProduto!=d.idProduto
```

Só que esta consulta continua retornando registros que estão também na tabela destaques, não funcionou como esperado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, para fins de organização vamos manter a tabela de interesse (produto) na esquerda, e a de referência (destaques) na direita, assim podemos usar um `LEFT JOIN`.

O `LEFT JOIN` é adequado, pois queremos o que tem na esquerda, mesmo não tendo correspondência, e não nos interessa o que tem na da direita sem correspondência.

Em seguida, vamos condicionar a retornar onde os dados da direita forem nulos.

O resultado é esse:

```
SELECT
   p.*
FROM
   produto p
   LEFT JOIN destaques d ON p.idProduto = d.idProduto
WHERE
   ISNULL(d.idProduto);
```

Note que não podemos quebrar o vínculo do `JOIN`, que é este:

```
   ON p.idProduto=d.idProduto
```

afinal, esta é a condição que relaciona as duas tabelas. Uma vez relacionadas, o que filtra os resultados é o `WHERE`. E a condição desejada é quando não houver correspondência, portanto, nulo:

```
WHERE ISNULL(d.idProduto);
```

Entender os `JOIN`s adequados para cada situação é importante. Sugiro leitura disto:

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/70)