# Problema com SELECT

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte `SELECT`

```
SELECT t.nome, count(t.id)
FROM Partidas p
LEFT JOIN Times t ON p.codTimeCasa = t.id
OR p.codTimeVisitante = t.id
GROUP BY t.nome
```

Gostaria que ele retornasse os times que não tem ligação com a tabela `partidas`, no entanto ele só retorna os que tem, alguém saberia a resolução desse problema?

Comment: Inverta os lados (ou o tipo de join), pra começar. SELECT FROM times LEFT JOIN partidas. afinal você quer os times. Sobre retornar os sem ligação, foi o que eu respondi aqui: [Como retornar apenas os registros sem correspondência em um JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159214/70)

Comment: @Bacco era isso mesmo muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que utilizando uma subconsulta com NOT EXISTS, você consegue resolver isso.

```
SELECT t.nome, count(t.id)
FROM Partidas p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL From Time t WHERE t.id = p.codTimeCasa OR t.id = p.codTimeVisitante)
GROUP BY t.nome
```

Nesse link tem mais detalhes:
https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta, mas o que eu preciso é dos times que tenham partidas e dos times que não tenham, este seu select retornou o seguinte erro :ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t" LINE 1: SELECT count(t.id).