# Consulta MySql para exibir registros não vinculados a uma determinada empresa

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Preciso criar uma consulta no `SQL`.

Eu possuo três tabelas:

```
TABELA 1: EMPRESA
emp_codigo (chave primaria)
emp_nome

TABELA 2: PALAVRAS_CHAVE
pal_codigo (chave primaria)
pal_nome

TABELA 3: VINCULO
vin_codigo (chave primaria)
vin_empresa (chave secundaria de emp_codigo)
vin_palavra (chave secundaria de pal_codigo)
```

Estou tentando montar uma *query* para exibir apenas as palavras-chave que não foram vinculadas **à empresa especificada na consulta**.

**Exemplo**:

> vamos considerar que a tabela de palavras-chave possua 5 palavas-chave: A, B, C, D e E, e que a empresa "Supermercado Boa Ideia" possua um vínculo com as palavras A, C e E. Logo, preciso que a consulta retorne para mim apenas B e D quando esta empresa for pesquisada.

**Detalhe: não trata-se apenas de listar registros que não tenham correspondência, mas também filtrar os registros de acordo com a empresa especificada na pesquisa.**

Comment: Duplicata de [Como retornar apenas os registros sem correspondência em um JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159214/70) ou de [Como criar pesquisa no MySQL que retorne linhas sem correspondência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109881/70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que pegar tudo da tabela palavra e fazer um left join com a tabela de vinculos, em seguida na clausula where, adicionar a condição onde vinculo for null, pois não encontrou nenhuma palavra lá:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM palavra_chave p
LEFT JOIN vinculo v
ON v.vin_palavra = p.pal_codigo
AND v.vin_empresa = [sua_empresa]
WHERE v.vin_codigo IS NULL
```

Comment: Olá Arllon, fiz exatamente isso, funcionou perfeitamente, o grande problema é que não está especificando uma empresa na query, ou seja, ele está filtrando as palavras-chaves não vinculadas considerando todas as empresas e não apenas uma.

Comment: só adicionar AND vin_empresa = id_empresa

Comment: Fiz isso, mas daí então ele não exibe nenhuma palavra-chave, independente se está vinculada ou não. :/

Comment: o grande problema está exatamente na hora de puxar a palavra chave não vinculada para uma determinada empresa.

Comment: EDITEI, o filtro tem que ser no JOIN

Comment: Perfeito Arllon, funcionou certinho, muito obrigado!

Comment: Tranquilo, por nada!